# Empty parameters passed while using POST in android for raw json data

Tags: android

I am making a new android application and i am a beginner. starting with my Login Activity, i am trying to use POST for sending parameters. but when i debug i found no parameters being passed. Tried almost many answers in stack overflow, none solved my issue. Can anyone help

```
           private void jsonRequestLogin() {
    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = Constants.LOGIN_URL;
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("Username", uName.getText().toString().trim());
        jsonBody.put("Password", paswd.getText().toString().trim());
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the logs for better understanding?

Comment: @HappySingh When i searched for 'error in logcat; I am getting like:   com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Comment: Timeout error will happen when your server did not respond. But as your question says it's not passing the JSON object.

Comment: When i debug i found its not passing json object@HappySingh

Comment: I have added an answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getParams()` method for requesting the parameters

```
private void check() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:" + response);

                        try {
                            JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = responseArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            //Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: jsonArray " + responseArray);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error);
                Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Some error occurred try after sometimes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("param1",param1);
                params.put("param2", param2;
                //Log.d(TAG, "getParams: " + params);
                return params;
            }
        };
        addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, "");

    }
```

Comment: this is an alternative solution. try to solve the code which has been put into the question.

Comment: How you debugged and founded no parameters being passed.??

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the headers method and put content type init.

```
@Override
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

     HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
     headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
     return headers;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use retrofit

[Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

[Retrofit 2](https://github.com/tutsplus/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android)